# Generic server hard drive brackets

Tags: hard-drive

I have an older server of a particular brand that I'm looking to refurb. The production applications have moved elsewhere and I want to re-purpose it for developement/test work. This involves replacing the power supply, installing more RAM, and replacing and adding hard drives.

Which brings me to the brackets. The pricing for matching brackets from the original vendor through normal channels is ridiculous: $80 on a good day for $2 worth of material with no significant moving parts or electronics. The bracket literally costs more than the drive I'll be mounting in it.

One option is ebay. I can get brackets for about $10. But we have an institutional dislike for buying via eBay (really: Paypal, but there are other reasons, too). The other option is a generic bracket.

Can I get generic hard drive brackets that fit most major server brands? What do I look for to know if it will fit?

This is at one level about a specific server and problem I have today, but I'd also like to know how to do this again for the next server. Thus, I'm avoiding mentioning the specific brand for now, and I'm *not* asking for a specific product. I want to know how to find a good product on my own both now and in the future. I will say this server still has 3.5" slots.

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic standard for hot-swap drives and there's no one-fits-all either. Each vendor has its own form factor which additionally varies through generations. So, it usually is preferred to buy more of the same in order to swap between them.

There's no alternative to using the original brackets short of replacing the drive cage(s).

But eBay isn't the only source for used parts, fortunately.